# Mechanism of 5‐(iodomethyl)oxolan‐2‐one synthesis from 4‐pentenoic acid and iodine in acetonitrile

Tags: organic-chemistry, halogenation

There is a question in my organic chemistry textbook with an answer. What it doesn't explain (and neither does my theory textbook, I checked) is the mechanism involved in the reaction. The reaction is as follows:

[image: synthesis of 5‐(iodomethyl)oxolan‐2‐one]

Can someone help me?

Comment: If the reaction was simply iodine adding to a double bond do you know how it works?

Comment: Well, yes. A Iodonium ion is formed, then another iodine attacks the ion from the other side, is that not right?

Comment: Well, as product suggests, something different attacked...

Comment: @ClaudioLancia Well I- is not a great nucleophile, and internal nucleophilic attack goes better than external nucleophilic attack. Carboxylate may not be a great nucleophile but it is internal, and the formation of 5-membered rings is favoured. See where this is going?

Comment: Ok, so does the carboxylate form the ring before the Iodine attack?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodolactonization

Comment: Oh, I get it now! Thanks a lot for the help. I didn't know the name of the reaction (especially since the exercise was in the alkene section, and my book didn't mention anything about Halolactonization), so this is a great help!

Comment: @ClaudioLancia Now that you understand, could you write up your own answer to summarize what you learned?

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodolactonization
I+ reacts with the CC-π electron donor. A cyclic iodonium three-membered ring intermediate is formed. The carboxylate group opens the electrophilic intermediate to form the product lactone. 5-membered rings (gamma-lactones) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactone are prefered due to optimum entropic and enthalpic parameters of activation.

Comment: Uh ... Why the -1?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Well, it's not my downvote, but there are many bad details - links to improve, weird wording/terminology, e.g. it's simply cyclic iodonium not "epi-iodium" etc.

Comment: In this case, the regioselectivity (to form the 5-membered instead of the 6-membered ring) also has a stereoelectronic factor: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/106846/16683